# Getting error in hasClass for react jest testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, jss

I have started jest testing for my react component and this one is my first test. my component code is

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import uuidv1 from 'uuid';
import withStyles from 'react-jss';

const styles ={
    keyvaluestyle:{
        fontSize: props => props.keyvalueFontsize,
        display: props => props.keyvalueDisplay,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        width: props => props.keyvalueWidth,
        margin: props => props.keyvalueMargin,
    }
}

const KeyValueJCpenny1 = ({

children,keyvalId,keyId,valueId, classes}) =>{
    return(
        <div className={classes.keyvaluestyle} data-element-type-id="KEY_VALUE_CONTAINER" data-element-id={keyvalId} data-key-id={keyId} data-clickable-value-id={valueId} data-component-name="true">
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

KeyValueJCpenny1.propTypes = {
    /**
     * KeyValue label for JCpenny form 1.
     */
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    keyvalId:PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    keyId : PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    valueId : PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    keyJCpennyClass : PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
KeyValueJCpenny1.defaultProps = {
    keyId : uuidv1(),
    keyvalId : uuidv1(),
    valueId : uuidv1(),
    children : 'key of jcpenny',
    keyJCpennyClass : 'keyJCpenny1'
};


export default withStyles(styles)(KeyValueJCpenny1)
```

and my test code is

```
import React from 'react';
import {configure, shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';

import KeyValueJCpenny1 from '../KeyValueJCpenny1/KeyValueJCpenny1';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({adapter:new Adapter()});


describe('key value container',()=>{
    it('renders container for key and value', ()=>{
        const wrapper = mount(<KeyValueJCpenny1  className="keyvalue"/>);
        expect(wrapper.find('.keyvaluestyle').hasClass('keyvaluestyle').to.equal(true))
    })
})
```

But I am getting error for my

[image]

can you please help me to solve this issue.Or how can I do the unit testing for my components

Comment: The best way to understand the issue would be to log `wrapper .debug()` to the console to see what enzyme has rendered. My guess is that the className is wrong as JSS create them on its own so it will look like `keyvaluestyle-1-2` or something like this. Also the names are not reliable so every time you change the styles object the class names will be regenerated. An easier way to test this would be using snapshots

Comment: Thanks. This issue is solved by using snapshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test code should be

```
    import React from 'react';
    import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

    import KeyValueJCpenny1 from '../KeyValueJCpenny1/KeyValueJCpenny1';

    describe('<KeyValueJCpenny1/>', () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {    
        jest.mock('uuid', () => {
            return {
                uuidv1: jest.fn(() => 1)
            };
        });
        const tree = renderer
        .create(<KeyValueJCpenny1 className="keyvalue" keyvalueWidth='30%' keyvalueDisplay='inline-block' keyvalueMargin="10px 10px 0 0">
        test1 Key:</KeyValueJCpenny1>)
        .toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```